# receber json_encode ( (array) $objj) no jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho o seguinte *retorno* do **PHP** por **JSON** através de **AJAX**:

```
[
  "ok",
  [
    [
      {
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000idCelula":"17",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000data":"2019-01-30",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000presentes":"0",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000visitas":"0",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000criancas":"0",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000decisoes":"0",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000discipulados":"0",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000jejum":"s",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000evangelismo":"s",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000supervisao":"s",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000oferta":"30"
      },
      {
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000idCelula":"17",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000data":"2019-02-01",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000presentes":"10",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000visitas":"2",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000criancas":"2",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000decisoes":"6",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000discipulados":"1",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000jejum":"n",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000evangelismo":"n",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000supervisao":"n",
        "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000oferta":"0"
      }
   ]
 ]
]
```

Basicamente fiz um `(array) $objeto` no **PHP** para poder usar `json_encode ()` pois são ***retornos de objetos PHP***

Agora, pretendo usar esse **array** de *2* **posições**`

```
retorno [ 0 ] = "ok";
retorno [ 1 ] = array PHP de objetos convertidos por (array) com vários índices;
```

Pegar a **posição [ 1 ]** do **array** e fazer um `foreach`.

```
resultado.forEach(function(reuniao, index){     

    html  = '<h2>' + reuniao.idCelula + '</h2>';
    html += '<ul class="vertical">';
    html += '  <li><label class="labelPequeno">Data</label> : ' + reuniao.data + '</li>';
    html += '</ul>';    

});
```

**Obs.:**

O meu *propósito* aqui é transformar o *retorno*:

```
"\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000idCelula"
```

em

```
"CelulasReunioesidCelula"
```

e, de preferência assim caso seja possível:

```
"idCelula"
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Vc já conseguiu fazer a parte do ajax? Onde, aqui na pergunta, está algum método do jQuery, como vc cita no título? Não entendi bem "onde vc está com dificuldade"...

Comment: sim: a parte que está assim: "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000idCelula":"17", já é o retorno do ajax. Aqui está normal. Agora preciso transformar esse retorno que no console sai assim : CelulasReunioes idCelula, em apenas assim: idCelula, isso no jQuery. Perceba que  \u0000 significa um espaço em branco

Comment: `CelulasReunioes` é o nome da sua classe no PHP? Se sim, como vc formou esse JSON? Pelo que entendi, o seu problema está na formação do JSON. É melhor vc corrigir isso no PHP, não acha? O que acha de [edit] a pergunta e postar o seu código PHP, se for o caso?

Comment: (array) $objeto.  Assim formei o array PHP, Mas ele entrega algo assim "\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000idCelula":"17". para os índeces. Ele coloca um espaço antes e outro depois do nome da Classe

Comment: Te serve uma resposta que "corrija" o seu PHP? Quando digo corrigir, significa fazer de uma outra forma a qual acho mais adequado. Aí vc julga se é melhor pra sua aplicação...

Comment: sim, mas seria convertendo o objeto em em array atributo por atributo ou existe uma função mais direta como o que faz a (array) $objeto°

Comment: A minha resposta já explica e exemplifica. Confesso que ainda estou curioso! Como você conseguiu chegar a um JSON com o nome da classe em cada atributo? Tentei imitar seu JSON, mas não consegui! @_@

Comment: é como expliquei, converti objetos em array com a função (array) $objeto.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89169/discussion-between-lipespry-de-folga-and-carlos-rocha).

Answer (score 0):

Como proposto nos comentários, vou reformular seu PHP <strike>(que não foi postado, mas, digamos que, desenvolvi essa parte do zero)</strike>.

```
<?php
class CelulasReunioes
{
    public $idCelula, $data, $presentes, $visitas,
        $criancas, $decisoes, $discipulados, $jejum,
        $evangelismo, $supervisao, $oferta;

    public function __construct($dados)
    {
        $this->idCelula = $dados[0];
        $this->data = $dados[1];
        $this->presentes = $dados[2];
        $this->visitas = $dados[3];
        $this->criancas = $dados[4];
        $this->decisoes = $dados[5];
        $this->discipulados = $dados[6];
        $this->jejum = $dados[7];
        $this->evangelismo = $dados[8];
        $this->supervisao = $dados[9];
        $this->oferta = $dados[10];
    }

}

$obj1 = new CelulasReunioes(
    array(
        '17', '2019-01-30', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', 's', 's', 's', '30'
    )
);
$obj2 = new CelulasReunioes(
    array(
        '17', '2019-02-01', '10', '2', '2', '6', '1', 'n', 'n', 'n', '0'
    )
);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$retorno = array('ok', array($obj1, $obj2));

echo json_encode($retorno, true);
```

É uma classe simples, só para simularmos a formação do JSON... Ignore a minha classe, apenas crie seu JSON como no meu exemplo.

Nomeado `json.php`, este arquivo me retorna o JSON da seguinte forma (formatado via [JSONLint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)):

```
["ok", [{
    "idCelula": "17",
    "data": "2019-01-30",
    "presentes": "0",
    "visitas": "0",
    "criancas": "0",
    "decisoes": "0",
    "discipulados": "0",
    "jejum": "s",
    "evangelismo": "s",
    "supervisao": "s",
    "oferta": "30"
}, {
    "idCelula": "17",
    "data": "2019-02-01",
    "presentes": "10",
    "visitas": "2",
    "criancas": "2",
    "decisoes": "6",
    "discipulados": "1",
    "jejum": "n",
    "evangelismo": "n",
    "supervisao": "n",
    "oferta": "0"
}]]
```

---

Agora, no cliente (HTML/JavaScript):

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/json.php',
    dataType: 'json'
})
.done(function(resultado){
    resultado[1].forEach(function(reuniao, index){
        let html  = '<h2>' + reuniao.idCelula + '</h2>';
        html += '<ul class="vertical">';
        html += '  <li><label class="labelPequeno">Data</label> : ' + reuniao.data + '</li>';
        html += '</ul>';
        // Aqui o html já está pronto para o uso! Aplique-o onde quiser.
        console.log(html);
    });
});
```

Basicamente, adicionei o índice `1` no `forEach` a fim de fazer a repetição apenas no `array` que contém os objetos: `resultado[1].forEach(...);`.

No final da repetição, joguei um `console.log(html)` a fim de testes. Basta você substituir essa parte do código conforme sua necessidade.

Se quiser ver tudo funcionando, pode baixar no meu [GitHub/LipESprY](https://github.com/lipespry/lsi-sopt/tree/master/PHP/receber-json-encode-array-objj-no-jquery%5B360048%5D) e simular no seu ambiente.

PS: Fiz a requisição do Ajax utilizando a biblioteca do *jQuery versão 3.3.1*;

Comment: pois é. dessa forma eu já tinha feito. Mas o que NÃO queria era exatamente isso. Percorrer o objeto atributo a atributo. Gostaria de sabe se existe uma outra função nativa do PHP que, assim como o (array) converta para array sem precisar percorrer os atributos

Comment: Colega, o `json_encode` já vai fazer todo esse serviço. Eu não percorri atributo por atributo. Apenas instanciei a classe 2 vezes pra ficar igual a sua! Parece que não estou entendendo seu objetivo... xD