# Converter objeto inteiro em array sem usar (array) objeto

Tags: php

Estou tentando converter um objeto **PHP** em **array** usando a **função**:

```
( array ) $objeto;
```

Converter *converte*, mas a **saída** `print_r ()` entrega:

```
"\u0000CelulasReunioes\u0000idCelula":"17",
```

Existe algum outra **função** do **PHP** que faça essa *conversão* sem adicionar o nome da **classe** aos **índices**?

Ou só dá mesmo *convertendo* o **objeto** em em `array` **atributo** por **atributo**?

Comment: Como assim, cara?! Na sua outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/360048/receber-json-encode-array-objj-no-jquery) eu já te entreguei isso "pronto"...